# Safari on Macs has issue with SSL cert, other browsers are fine

Tags: ssl, https

Working with a ticketing system site that must be accessed via HTTPS at https://www.threestages.net

Our images are hosted elsewhere ( https://wserver.flc.losrios.edu/~vapa/) and also accessed via HTTPS.

Example image:  https://wserver.flc.losrios.edu/~vapa/event_mastheads/1011_scrap_arts.jpg

We have multiple reports that Safari 4.1.3 on Macs is not displaying the images. We have no reports of this behavior from any other browser or platform.

Any one have any notion what that would be about?

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that Safari has an issue with the SSL Cert at https://wserver.flc.losrios.edu/

http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html let me know that

> The certificate is not trusted in all
>   web browsers. You may need to install
>   an Intermediate/chain certificate to
>   link it to a trusted root certificate.

Thanks for looking at this.  Valuable lessons learned:

1. Even if 4 out of 5 browsers accept an SSL Cert that doesn't mean they all do
2. Just because the sysadmin says it's not his problem/mistake doesn't make it so!
3. Check everything.  Then repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's common to have an "asset server" or CDN for images to speed up page loads.  Sounds like a timeout issue to me. Does Safari 5 work well?

Comment: I'll see what I can find out.  AFAIK it's strictly with Safari 4.1.3.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I can say that Safari 5.0.3 on my PC loads the images but it takes an unusually long time to do so.